Rsync --compare-dest with remote directory giving errors
On local Win11 machine, I'm using rsync v3.3 through Cygwin v3.5.3 and on my remote ubuntu 22.04 machine, I'm using rsync v3.2.7.
I have a source directory in my local machine whilst compare and destination directories are in my remote machine. I am comparing (local) source directory with (remote) compare directory and copying differences in (remote) destination directory. However, rsync is giving me error:
--compare-dest arg does not exist: username@remote-server:/absotute/path/to/compare/remote/dir
I am using the following rsync command:
rsync -aumChqP --modify-window=1 --compare-dest=username@remote-server:/absotute/path/to/compare/remote/dir/ /cygdrive/absotute/path/to/source/local/dir/ username@remote-server:/absotute/path/to/destination/remote/dir/
Note: It does NOT always give this error and in 1 out of 10 attempts, rsync compares local with remote directories and transfers the differences to the remote directory.
Update:
On suggestion of @Philippe, I am now using the following command to process rsync load (which works better):
rsync -aumChqP --modify-window=1 --compare-dest=/absotute/path/to/compare/remote/dir/ /cygdrive/absotute/path/to/source/local/dir/ username@remote-server:/absotute/path/to/destination/remote/dir/

Have you tried : --compare-dest=/absotute/path/to/compare/remote/dir/ ?

It works better by eliminating ssh username@remote-server from --compare-dest but it still sometimes reports errors like:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname remote-server: Name or service not known rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [sender=3.3.0]
